# Sending an integer in http PUT request in java

Tags: java, json, http, httpclient

I want to send **{"name":"super user","status":1}** but when i send i get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at com.service.RoleService.updateRole(RoleService.java:145)
    at com.service.RoleService.main(RoleService.java:176)
```

here is the code

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:31109/user/role/"+role_id);
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

        String input = "{\"name\":\""+name+"\",\"status\":"+status+"}";
        System.out.println(input);


        OutputStream outputStream = httpConnection.getOutputStream();

        outputStream.write(input.getBytes());

        outputStream.flush();

        if(httpConnection.getResponseCode() !=200){
            String error_resp;
           BufferedReader error_responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (httpConnection.getErrorStream()))); 
           while((error_resp = error_responseBuffer.readLine()) != null){
               System.out.println("Error responsecode => "+httpConnection.getResponseCode()+"error => "+error_resp);
               output = new JSONObject(error_resp);
           }
        }else {
            BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (httpConnection.getInputStream())));
            String httpresponse;
            StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
            while((httpresponse = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null){
                content.append(httpresponse);
            }
             output = new JSONObject(content.toString());
        }
        httpConnection.disconnect();
```

however when i send  **{"name":"super user","status":"1"}** the request is ok but the API has a validation that requires it to be sent as an integer and rejects it. and i cant change the api.

Comment: if your code works with one input but not another, that means your code is ok, the problem is the API you are sending to

Comment: Your code doesn't demonstrate where you are creating the Reader and getting the NullPointerException

Comment: is the error you showed client or server-side? what does the api expect to be an integer? do you have control over the server side? you should improve your question

Comment: @nandsito the api expects  {"name":"super user","status":1}  but when it try sending it using the code above it breaks. with a null pointer exception. but when i call it with  {"name":"super user","status":"1"} the code doesnt break its ok only that the api rejects it in its validation

Comment: @ControlAltDel i have edited there is the full code calling the http request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to create a Reader for the response for your URL call, but likely the socket has already been closed. You should check your httpConnection.getXXXStream calls to make sure the httpConnection is still alive and the return value from the getStream calls is not null.

-- edit --

Your check for `responseCode != 200` is a problem. None of the response codes in the 100s and 200s are errors, and will not use the error stream. Otherwise, you should check that the inputstreams you are getting from the httpConnection, like

```
    if(httpConnection.getResponseCode() !=200){
        String error_resp;
        InputStream in = httpConnection.getErrorStream();
        if (in == null) return; // check if the error stream is null
       BufferedReader error_responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            (httpConnection.getErrorStream()))); 
       while((error_resp = error_responseBuffer.readLine()) != null){
           System.out.println("Error responsecode => "+httpConnection.getResponseCode()+"error => "+error_resp);
           output = new JSONObject(error_resp);
       }
    }else {
        InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
        if (in == null) return; // check inputstream
        BufferedReader responseBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (in)));
        String httpresponse;
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        while((httpresponse = responseBuffer.readLine()) != null){
            content.append(httpresponse);
        }
         output = new JSONObject(content.toString());
    }
    httpConnection.disconnect();
```

Comment: how could you demonstrate please?